# Auto fill the current date and date before a month in textbox using Jquery then filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, textbox, datepicker

my problem is to auto fill the those two date on textbox **when page load** and then according to the date to filter them using datepicker

the code i have now

```
                  <td >

                    <label for="from">Start date:</label>

                    <input type="text" id="from" />

                    <label for="to">End date:</label>

                    <input type="text" id="to" />


                </td>
```

and for the script

```
 $(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
        }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function( selectedDate ) {
            $( "#from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate", selectedDate  );
        }
    });
  });
```

any help is appreciated!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you want the min/max Date set as indicated in your `onSelect` handler, so:

EDIT: Added code to prepopulate the date.

EDIT2: And again for a different requirement not stated in the question.

```
$(function() {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "-3w",
        maxDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }
    }).datepicker('setDate', '-3w');
    $("#to").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        minDate: "-3w",
        changeMonth: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onSelect: function(selectedDate) {
            $("#from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }
    }).datepicker('setDate', '+1w');;
});
```

Comment: I just test it, it wont work, how about auto fill the date first, do you have any idea?

Comment: Thanks, this enable the textbox to prepopulate the value, and they are the same date, i want the 1st textbox a month earlier than the second one, also, how to I fire an event that can do a filter when page load

Comment: You'll want to update your question, because as it stands, you have the same `defaultDate` option on both. What do you mean "do a filter when page load"? By setting the `maxDate` option on the `#from` datepicker, you are already doing the filter which would occur when the selection occurs on the `#to` datepicker.

Comment: I am sorry, maybe the code is wrong, but in my logic, the default date for the first one should be three weeks less than the second textbox, thanks

Comment: I'm assuming that the requirement is for the first one to be 3 weeks ago and the second one to be 1 week in the future. Further changes you can puzzle out yourself from the documentation http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/